# Why is it impossible to include module type from functor parameter module into module type in resulting module of functor?

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

OCaml doesn't provide the ability to create a module type by functor directly. But, It allows some manipulations with the nested module type. So, I can use module type from parameter to bind module type in the result:

```
module CONTAINER = struct
  module type S = sig
    val a : int
  end
end

module COPY (CONTAINER : sig module type S end) = struct
  module type S = CONTAINER.S
end 

module type S_FROM_CONTAINER = COPY(CONTAINER).S
```

`S_FROM_CONTAINER` isn't abstract. It is necessary to provide `a` to apply `S_FROM_CONTAINER`.

```
(*
module Impl : S_FROM_CONTAINER = struct
end 

> Error: Signature mismatch:
> Modules do not match: sig end is not included in S_FROM_CONTAINER  
> The value `a' is required but not provided
*)

module Impl : S_FROM_CONTAINER = struct
  let a = 42
end
```

Also, I can use `S` from `CONTAINER` as a type of module in module type in the resulting module:

```
module AS_TYPE_OF_IMPL (CONTAINER : sig module type S end) = struct
  module type S = sig
    module Impl : CONTAINER.S 
  end
end 

module type IMPL_CONTAINER_S = 
  AS_TYPE_OF_IMPL(CONTAINER).S
```

`Impl` module in `IMPL_CONTAINER_S` isn't abstract module type too:

```
(* module ImplContainer : IMPL_CONTAINER_S = struct
     module Impl = struct end
   end

> Error: Signature mismatch:
> Modules do not match:
>   sig module Impl : sig end end
> is not included in
>   IMPL_CONTAINER_S
> In module Impl:
> Modules do not match: sig end is not included in CONTAINER.S
> In module Impl:
> The value `a' is required but not provided
*)

module ImplContainer : IMPL_CONTAINER_S = struct
  module Impl = struct let a = 42 end
end
```

That's fine. I think it is a powerful tool. But I found one limitation that makes me sad. It is impossible to include this module type into another one.

```
module EXTEND_S (CONTAINER : sig module type S end) = struct
  module type S = sig
    include CONTAINER.S
    val extention : int
  end
end
```

Or

```
module AS_PART_OF_IMPL (CONTAINER : sig module type S end) = struct
  module type S = sig
    module Impl : sig
      include CONTAINER.S
      val extention : int
    end 
  end 
end
```

> `include CONTAINER.S`
>         `^^^^^^^^^^^`
> Error: This module type is not a signature

Why I can't do this? For me, it looks like some gap, nor only in the compiler but in language conception too. What I miss to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In brief, `include` are not part of the type system of modules and they work on signatures by inlining the content of the signature. And adding an `include` expression in the module system is not that straightforward because one cannot include any module type in any context. Consider for instance:

```ml
module F(X:sig module type x module type y end) = struct
  module type result = sig 
    include x
    include y
  end
end
```

is not always valid. Consider for instance,

```ml
module type x = sig
  type t
  val x: t
end
module type y = sig
  type t
  val y: t
end
```

then

```ml
module type t = sig
  include x
  include y
end
```

yields an error

> ```
> Error: Illegal shadowing of included type t/863 by t/865
>       Line 2, characters 2-11:
>         Type t/863 came from this include
>       Line 3, characters 2-10:
>         The value x has no valid type if t/863 is shadowed
> ```

Thus `include s` is not always valid and making it possible to include abstract type module would require to refine the module type system to capture this condition.

Moreover, having module types with a dynamic number of runtime components would require a different compilation scheme because querying a path inside a module can no longer be reduced to querying a statistically-known index in a block.